# How to crop the green colored rectangle from an image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I need to crop an image for further processing on it using opencv and python.  I need to crop the region inside the green colored rectangle in the image. The rectangle is drawn using "haar_cascade_fullbody_Detector"

The code is as follows :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

bodydetection = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
img = cv2.imread('original.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
body = bodydetection.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.009, 5)

for x, y, w, h in body:
   # so we slightly shrink the rectangles to get a nicer output.
   pad_w, pad_h = int(0.15*w), int(0.02*h)
   cv2.rectangle(img, (x+pad_w+10, y+pad_h+10), (x+w-pad_w, y+h-pad_h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
   cv2.imshow('img',img)
   crop_img = img[x:x+w, y:y+h]
   cv2.imshow('crop',crop_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The input image is :

[image]

The output of haar cascade is  :

[image]

after the crop the image is :

[image]

Please suggest any solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I got the answer. The line of crop_img should be modified as

```
 crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

This produces required output.This is because in opencv the img coordinated sequence is y-coordinates and then x-coordinates.

Comment: Yes that is the correct way to crop images. Specifically, we are able to do this since images are stored as a Numpy array in OpenCV.